# Homeomorphism examples

Tags: general-topology

What's a homeomorphism?

a. any countable $f\colon \mathbb {N} \to \mathbb {Q}$

b. $f\colon \mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}$, $x \mapsto x^3$

c. $f\colon [0,2\pi ) \to S^1 = \{ z \in \mathbb {C}\,|\,|z|=1\}$, $\varphi \mapsto e^{i \varphi }$

I'm very sure that b doesn't work because it's not bijective and I think that everything is fine with a. But I'm really unsure about c, can someone explain it for me?

Comment: Why isn't $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, x \mapsto x^3$ bijective?

Comment: Why do you think (a) should be a homeomorphism? What about the map $f(n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$?

Comment: Assuming that you’re talking about the usual topologies on $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb Q$, there is **no** function $f:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q$ that is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. There exist bijections $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q$, but none of them can be a homeomomorhism. In fact, let $x \in \mathbb N$. Then $\{x\}$ is open in $\mathbb N$, but $f(\{x\}) = \{f(x)\}$ is never open in $\mathbb Q$.

b. It is a homeomorphism. Its inverse is $f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ which is continuous.

c. $[0,2\pi)$ is non-compact, $S^1$ is compact. Thus they cannot be homeomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition** Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces ; let $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be a bijection. If $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous, then $f$ is a homeomorphism. Now, back to your examples

(a) $f\colon \Bbb N \to \Bbb Q$, you must define before saying $f$ is homeomorphism.

(b) the function $f(x)=x^3$ is indeed  bijection and $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. So, $f$ is homeomorphism.

Try to check $c$. I hope that helps